# PHP Not Finding My header.html File In Directory

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on using PHP to give myself the same header, navigation and footer elements across all pages, but I have a problem; for some reason the .php file isn't recognizing the header.html file for a include("/header.html")

.php file

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<title>Sample Game Type</title>

</head>
<body>
    <?php include("/header.html"); ?>
    <div id="gamelisting"><!--Gametype Shortcuts-->
        <a href="http://www.website.ca/game-types/carpe.html">
            <div class="gametype">'Carpe' (also known as just Carpe)</div>
        </a>
        <div class="gametype">Other Game Here</div>
        <div class="gametype">Add more as neccessary</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gameinfo"><!--Information about game type-->
        <h2 style="text-align:center;"></h2><!--Name-->
        <h3>Description</h3>
        
        <h3>Objective</h3>
        
        <h3>Rules</h3>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

And then my header.html file.

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Header</title>
</head>
<body>      
    <li><!--Header Buttons-->
        <a href="http://www.website.ca">
            <div id="header">
                Home
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.website.ca/mods.html">
            <div id="header">
                Mods
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.website.ca/selling.html">
            <div id="header">
                Selling
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.website.ca/gallery.html">
            <div id="header">
                Gallery
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.website.ca/contact.html">
            <div id="header">
                Contact
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong? The header.html file is in the root of my pubic_html file with the .php page I'm trying to connect with being in directory /game-types

Comment: Just an aside, you probably shouldn't have a html, head tags in the the header.html file since you already have those in your php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `<?php include("/header.html"); ?>` you are really saying look for a file named header.html at the root of my entire filesystem; not in your public_html directory (or even in a predefined include_path) with all your other files, like /path/to/public_html/header.html, you are literally looking for a file at /header.html.

It sounds like you want to include a file relative to the current directory.

Something like this:

```
include(__DIR__ . '/header.html');
```

or

```
include('header.html');
```

Comment: So would I do better to say <?php include("/public_html/header.html"); ?> If that is, in fact the proper path from the root of my file system?

I'm trying to make a single header.html file work for the entire site with multiple directories.

Comment: `__DIR__` is a constant which will return the current relative directory, so if you are in the php file `/path/to/public_html/index.php` and using `__DIR__` it will return `/path/to/public_html`

Comment: Okay, however my I am in /path/to/public_html/game-types/webpage.php but I also have files in /path/to/public_html/ and other directories that I want to have access to this header file, not only those in the /path/to/public_html/ directory.

Comment: Then link relative to those directories. I.e. if I have a file named lol.html directory above my current directory then I need to look at `__DIR__ . '/../lol.html'` or link via the full path. It's up to you.

Comment: Well something seems to have worked, but now I'm getting an error telling me "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/a3442538/public_html/game-types/carpe-testiculum.php on line 9**"

Line 9 is "**<?php include(__DIR__'/public_html/header.html'); ?>**"

Comment: @SFN Put a `.` between `_DIR_` and `'/public_html/header.html'`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. After messing around with my files I;m still unable to make it work with a single header.html file in my /public_html/ directory so I've settled on simply maintaining an up-to-date version of each common file in every individual directory. It's still a hell of a lot simpler than having to edit every webpage separately.